# Vincular código generado Travel app_blazor ó Travel app_angular a visual studio code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo, necesito preguntarle lo siguiente tengo un código generado por la herramienta App Builder y necesito vincularlo a una aplicación que tengo en Visual Studio Code (C# ASP.NET), necesito saber cómo puedo realizar dicho proceso con el fin de que el formulario de login, mejore la apariencia de acuerdo al código generado por la herramienta mencionada.

Comment: A que te referis con vincularlo? podrias explicar un pcoo mas tu problema? ademas, la aplicacion no la tenes en visual studio code. La tenes en ASP.NET, y usas vs code como ide.

Comment: Cordial saludo, me refiero a que desde App Builder, se genera un codigo el cual puede ser Travel app_angular ó Travel app_blazor, en App Builder se generó el script que permite al usuario ingresar su nombre de usuario y contraseña, la idea es mejorar la apariencia del archivo que tiene como nombre Login.cshtml, para ello fue que se realizó la creación de la plantilla en App Builder. la primera plantilla la extraje a la carpeta Views del proyecto en Visual Studio 2022. La pregunta es como vinculo lo que se me genero en App Builder a la aplicación que la empresa tiene desarrollada?.

Comment: otra vez.. que es vincular? a que te referis con eso? vos generaste codigo con una herramienta que genera codigo automatico. Ahora, que queres hacer con eso?

Comment: Lo que se necesita, es que el aspecto de la pagina de login que tengo en C# ASP.NET  adquiera  el aspecto de lo que he descargado o que me genero el App Builder.

Comment: O sea, queres copiar el codigo? sabes que estas preguntando? porque yo no...

Comment: Estimado @MartínHernández ¿estas utilizando [App Builder (de Infragistics)](https://www.infragistics.com/products/appbuilder/help/app-builder-overview)? Es una herramienta de una empresa que tiene soporte podrias comenzar buscando por ahi (o preguntando en sus foros). Yo estaba buscando como ["personalizar" basado en temas el App Builder](https://www.infragistics.com/products/appbuilder/help/app-themes/app-themes#how-to-customize--apply-app-themes). Pero no te podremos ayudar si no vemos el codigo que genera la herramienta.

Comment: Cordial saludo estimado @JoseA.Fernandez en la siguiente dirección esta el repositorio del código que me genera el App Builder: https://github.com/hecamava/codigogeneradoAppBuilder                                           Gracias!.

Comment: Deberias, colocar el codigo que necesites que te ayudemos exactamente. Porque dices "vincular", pero mirando el codigo es una app que puedes copiar o pegar en otro proyecto (incluso con las librerias que genera) y modificarlo con tu estilo propio. Todo esto por tu inquietud *"que el formulario de login, mejore la apariencia "*, entonces toma la pagina Login (*/Pages/Login.razor*) y dale el formato reformula la pregunta mas arriba que contenga lo que vas haciendo. Asi ayudamos puntualmente. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jose A. Fernandez,  muchas gracias es que lo que estoy haciendo es un trabajo para la empresa en que trabajo, mi jefe me dijo que descargara el App builder de la empresa Infragistics y que creara un diseño en esa herramienta para implementarlo en el sitio web que ellos tienen, soy nuevo en ese trabajo y jamás he utilizado esa herramienta, el próximo martes que vuelva a la empresa le estaré comentando según las recomendaciones hechas, un cordial saludo y muchas gracias.